# Will new versions of Blender support my models from 2013 version?

Tags: modeling, export

I must use old (2013) version of blender for a bit of time.
I'm not doing so complex work, just simple Modeling & Unwrapping. 
So i hope, if i will want to open my blender files in newer version, everything will be okay, right?

Comment: Please explain why you [must use old (2013)].  Just try your old file with the latest version today and test.  Most people would encourage you to use latest version for simple work.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just a stretch to assume that "everything" will be okay, but Blender has long had backwards compatibility as part of its overall design philosophy, so that in almost all cases, you can load old blender content in newer versions, even retaining the UI of the older version.

Comment: Opening old models in newer versions will work fine. But if you save them in a newer version those new projects will no open in older versions.